# How to remove an inline element and insert it after the parent block element?

Tags: jquery

So I have a div into which a user inserts information. It usually ends up looking like this:

```
<div id="description">
  <p>Some introduction the user wrote</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text here that the user wrote</p>
  <img src="/path/to/first-image" /><span class="credit">Copyright Text</span>
  <p>More stuff that the user wrote and then he decides to insert an image. 
   So we get this inserted inline <img src="/path/to/second-image" /><span class="credit">Copyright Text</span></p>
</div>
```

I can't have `<img>` tags inserted into `<p>` tags. It ruins the page. So how do I 'cut' the `<img>` and the corresponding `<span>` tag with the copyright text and insert it all immediately after the `<p>` tag that it was just in? So I end up with this:

```
<div id="description">
  <p>Some introduction the user wrote</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text here that the user wrote</p>
  <img src="/path/to/first-image" /><span class="credit">Copyright Text</span>
  <p>More stuff that the user wrote and then he decides to insert an image. 
  So we get this inserted inline</p>
 <img src="/path/to/second-image" /><span class="credit">Copyright Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one alternative where [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) functions are applied, among others. This solution hasn't been thoroughly tested but at least in the above case this seems to work. I hope you find it okay :-)

```js
 var start = new Date().getTime();

//loop each paragraph that is child of div description
$("div#description > p").each(function(outerIndex) {

  $elem = $(this);

  //look for img or span element that is preceded (+) by img
  $elem.find("img, img + span").each(function(innerIndex) {

    if (innerIndex == 0) {
      //create temporaty extra div that is later removed            
      $elem.after($("<p id='temp'>"));
    }

    //append found element into temp div
    $("#temp").append($(this));

  });

  //detach children in temp div
  $tempChildren = $("#temp").children().detach();

  //append those after
  $("#temp").after($tempChildren);

  //remove temp div
  $("#temp").remove();

});

var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;

console.log("duration in milliseconds: " +time);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description">
  <p>Some introduction the user wrote</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text here that the user wrote</p>
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" /><span class="credit">Copyright Text</span>

  <p>More stuff that the user wrote and then he decides to insert an image. So we get this inserted inline
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" /><span class="credit">Copyright Text</span>

  </p>
</div>
```

Updated, here's an alternative way of doing with less jQuery method calls:

```js
var start = new Date().getTime();

      //loop each paragraph that is child of div description
     $("div#description > p").each(function(outerIndex) {

       $elem = $(this);

       //look for img or span element that is preceded (+) by img
       $elem.find("img, img + span").each(function(innerIndex) {

         if (innerIndex == 0) {

           $elem.after($(this));

           $elemMoved = $(this);

         } else {

           $elemMoved.after($(this));

           $elemMoved = $(this);
         }
       });
     });

     var end = new Date().getTime();
     var time = end - start;

     console.log("duration in milliseconds: " + time);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="description">
          <p>Some introduction the user wrote</p>
          <p>Some paragraph text here that the user wrote</p>
          <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" /><span class="credit">Copyright Text</span>

          <p>
              More stuff that the user wrote and then he decides to insert an image. So we get this inserted inline
              <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" /><span class="credit">Copyright Text</span>

          </p>
      </div>
```

The duration of the processing was around 6-7 milliseconds on average on my computer, and it was marginally faster than the original code that  took around 7-8 milliseconds on average. However when I ran the tests on Stackoverflow, the times were considerable faster, around 1-2 milliseconds for new function and  around 3-4 milliseconds for the old one. Perhaps the fastest processing can be achieved with native JavaScript.

Comment: It works rather well. I have a loop that already finds all `img` tags and adds an `id` attribute to them. `$('#Description img').each(function(i, e) {
            $(this).attr('id', 'Img'+i);
        });` 
Is there anyway to modify your code so that I can run the cut and paste process within the same loop above? I thought it may be better for performance but not sure.

Comment: @volumeone Hi, good that you asked, I was able to find marginally quicker solution which I updated to the answer :-)

Comment: @volumeone Excellent :-)

Comment: Can I ask why do we need the `$elemMoved = $(this);` ? I didn't understand what it was doing exactly sorry

Comment: @volumeone No problem, it took me a while and quite a bit of experimentation before I ended with the current solution.  So here is the answer: $elemMoved = $(this); is used to save temporarily the current element in each loop (the inner loop), so that during the next iteration of the each loop, the “new” current element: $(this);
can be easily appended in the right place by using:  $elemMoved.after($(this)); So it’s just used to save the element for the next iteration of each loop.

Comment: @volumeone Originally, I tried to find a solution on how to find the correct “next” element by using jQuery’ siblings() and nextUntil() methods but didn’t get those working in the right way. After some experimentation I finally discovered $elemMoved = $(this); which when used in this context is in my opinion quite similar to Linked Lists that are used in data structures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list but it was the first time I have applied Linked Lists in this context by using jQuery, so it was new to me too :-)

Comment: @volumeone Also forgot to tell you that I discovered a new behavior of jQuery for me while experimenting with this question. In each loop jQuery saves the value of  $elem and $elemMoved until it’s set with a new element value. I mean that’s why $elemMoved is available in the next round of each loop. To be honest, I don’t know why jQuery has this kind of functionality. Perhaps, I should make a question about this :-)

Comment: @volumeone Hi again :-) About the $elemMoved and why it saves the reference for the next iteration of each loop - well I had to ask the experts, and here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28644776/2048391

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correcly you wish to remove the last img and span out of the `<p>`
you could store the image and span in a variable `var temp = $("#description p > img, p > span.client");`

After you have your temp variable you need to get the parent by `var parent = $(temp).parent();`

After you done that you need to remove the imagine and span `$("#description p > img, p > span.client").remove();`

At the end you just simple append the `temp` variable to the div `parent.after(temp);`

Comment: Its not just the last one. I need to do it to all inline images

Comment: You could simply just remove the :last from the `$("#description img:last, span:last")`, this will get you all the img elements and spans in the `description div`

Comment: But it will get all of them, and some are not within a `<p>` tag. What will happen to those? I don't want to append to the end of the `#description` div, rather I want to append to the `<p>` that I just cut the img and span tags from. Should it be `var temp = $("#description p img, p span.credit")` ?

Comment: you should use `var temp = $("#description p > img, p > span.credit");` parent `>` child http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: Rather than append to the div, I want to append AFTER the `<p>` tag that I just cut the img and span tags from

Comment: Alright for that you can simply get the parent of the of the `temp` variable as `var parent = $(temp).parent();` and call the `.after` method to add after the `<p>` like `parent.after(temp);`