# Why jQuery's each loop’s function saves a reference to an element object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I discovered that jQuery saves a variable in an `each` loop’s function, if it has been set with a jQuery object reference. For example below `$elem` value stays the same during the second and third iteration of each method, and it refers to the first div.

```js
$("div").each(function(index) {

   //below $elem is initialized with div reference during first iteration
    if (index === 0)
       $elem = $(this);

    var text = "index: <span>" + index + ",</span> <span>$(this).html():</span> <span>" +     $(this).html() + ",</span><span> elem.html():</span> <span>" + $elem.html() + "</span>";

   $("#output").append("<li>" + text + "</li>");
 });
```

```css
li span {
   color: blue;
 }
 li span:nth-child(2) {
   color: red;
 }
 li span:nth-child(4) {
   color: green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>1 DIV</div>
<div>2 DIV</div>
<div>3 DIV</div>
<br />jQuery each loop's output:
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

I was kind of surprised that `$elem` doesn’t become `null` or `undefined` during the second iteration of `each` loop. Following that behavior the output has text: *1 DIV* on each three lines. Does anyone have an idea why `$elem` refers to the first `div` during second and third iteration of each method? – Thanks

Comment: Because `$elem` is a global variable.

Comment: Yes it's a global variable. Replace the line with `var $elem = $(this)`. jQuery isn't doing anything here, it's the way JavaScript as a language is designed.

Comment: Cheers, @Mouser I'll give points if you post it as answer. It looks like dfsq was the first to provide an answer, I'll accept his as the correct answer, but I'll give you upvote Mouser. But thanks for both of you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone have an idea why $elem refers to the first div during second and third iteration of each method?

Because you set global variable `$elem` in the first iteration and this variable never changes later. So in the loop and after loop is complete this variable will point to the first `div` jQuery object.

Never forget to declare variables with `var` keyword. Undeclared but initialized variables become global variables. As you can see it can lead to confusion and errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, - now I understand the issue and the behavior :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because a varialbe does not have a lexical scope by default. If it was declared as

```
var $elem
```

instead, it would be reset to undefined each time the function is run.

See the [variable statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) developer page for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer + info, it's helpful indeed :-)